# In Django ORM, is their an equivalent of the EntityFramework command EnsureCreated and EnsureDeleted?

Tags: django, entity-framework, orm

In EntityFramework, in addition to migrations, you have a command that will drop a database and/or create a database in one go:

```
_dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
_dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

This is very useful for initial development, experiments, demos and integration testing. Is there a command in Django that does the equivalent?